# Evaluate a string to a dictionary when there are null values in the dictionary

Tags: python, string, pandas, dictionary, null

I have a dataframe that looks like this (Thing_2 is being evaluated as a string):

```
ID           Thing           Thing_2
1             abc            [{"object_1": "a", "object_2": null}]
2             def            None
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
ID           Thing           Thing_2
1             abc            a
2             def            None
```

To do this I did the following steps:

```
def change_to_dict(row):
     t2 = row['Thing_2']
     if pd.notna(row['Thing_2']):
          t2 = t2.strip('[]') 
          t2 = ast.literal_eval(t2)
          return t2.get[0]
```

I keep getting a value_error: malformed node at the index where it's not null. I think that it's because there's a null value as the second value in the dictionary.

Comment: @Priya,  Is that your DataFrame looks like in the `Thing_2` column where it has 2 Keys and two values and you need to extract only first value out of it in the column?

Comment: @rafaelc I can't post the exact thing due to confidentiality, but that column dict looks like this 
```'Thing_2': {0: None,
  1: None,
  2: '{"object_1": "a", "object_2": null}'}```

Comment: @pygo yes, it is

Comment: Instead of `ast.literal_eval` use `json.loads` . You have to `import json` at the top of the documetn first.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
import json

def change_to_dict(row):
    t2 = row['Thing_2']
    if pd.notna(t2):
        t2_content = json.loads(t2)
        return ','.join(filter(bool, t2_content[0].values()))
```

Comment: returns ```KeyError: (0, 'occurred at index 0')``` with the issue pointing to the last line

Comment: Mh, my test seems to work: https://repl.it/repls/SquareExtrovertedAngles

Answer (score 0):

As i understand, I don't Know if that works for you.

### DataFrame:

```
>>> df
   ID Thing                                Thing_2
0   1   abc  [{"object_1": "a", "object_2": null}]
1   2   def                                   None
```

### Output:

you can achieve that using re module but you have to define what string / char you need to extract from the column.

```
>>> search_list = ['a']
>>> import re

>>> df['Thing_2'] = df.Thing_2.str.extract('({})'.format('|'.join(search_list)), flags=re.IGNORECASE, expand=False).str.lower().fillna('None')
>>> df
   ID Thing Thing_2
0   1   abc       a
1   2   def    None
```

This is valuable in case you have some handful of strings/word to be searched against  a particular column like `a` .

Comment: Don't you think this is very specific to 'a'?

Comment: @Danny, Indeed it is in this case to simulate the example given but you are not limited to `a` only that's what i said, you can pass a entire list , lets suppose you have values to extract `['a', 'b', 'c' 'd']` whatever the case...

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
import yaml
def change_to_dict(row):
  if pd.notna(row):
     t2 = row
     t2 = t2.strip('[]')
     t2 = yaml.load(t2)

     return list(t2.values())[0]
```

`df['Thing_2'].apply(lambda x: change_to_dict(x))`